# Registering generic types in Unity config

Tags: xml, configuration, unity-container

Oh! this is very strange issue. I'm going to register these two types, but there is nothing to be work well.

```
<unity>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="IEqualityComparer`1"
                   type="System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1, mscorlib" />
        <typeAlias alias="singleton"
                   type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />            
        <typeAlias alias="EqualityComparer`1"
                   type="System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1, mscorlib" />
    </typeAliases>
    <containers>
        <container>
            <types>
                <register type="IEqualityComparer`1"
                          mapTo="EqualityComparer`1">
                    <lifetime type="singleton" />
                </register>
            </types>
        </container>
    </containers>
</unity>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public class MyController : MyExtendedController {
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<int> _fakeComparer;

    public ResourcesController(IEqualityComparer<int> fakeComparer) {
        _fakeComparer = fakeComparer;
    }
}
```

And exception throws by Unity when resolving Controller:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MyController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type EqualityComparer`1 cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:
Resolving MyController,(none)
Resolving parameter "fakeComparer" of constructor   MyController(System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[[int, mscorelib]] fakeComparer)
Resolving System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1[int, mscorelib],(none) (mapped from System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[int, mscorelib], (none))
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Updated answer***

The reason is that `EqualityComparer<T>` is an abstract class, as you can see [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx). Unity cannot instantiate abstract classes, you have to provide a concrete implementation.

---

---

*First answer*

Did you have configured your server:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
section.Containers.Default.Configure(container);
```

Comment: I haven't any problem with configuring/reading configurations from config file. I have problem with resolving registered type by Unity. I have tested this issue with my own generic interface/class and that works find! But i can't figure IEqualityComparer/EqualityComparer out to be work.

Comment: "System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1, mscorlib" is for simplifying, my real alias definition is something like this: "System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"